# Rendering an animation from imported position/time data

Tags: python, scripting

I have written a physics simulation using C# and Rust. It's just a bunch of balls
moving around and interacting. Each ball has a position (x,y,z), color, and radius at any given point in time. Sometimes the balls also combine or split.

Right now I have a very slow and basic visualization using WPF, but I would like something that looks better, where I can maybe play around with camera perspectives and lighting to see what is going on in my simulation.

Here's what I have in mind:

1. Write the simulation data for each frame to a file that lists each object's position, color, and radius.
2. Load the files into Blender in such a way that it can animate them.

My questions:

1. What file format(s) should I use?
2. Is Blender the right program for this? I've never used any animation or rendering software before, so if some other program is more suitable, it's all the same to me in terms of the learning curve.

Comment: Hello and welcome ! As a whole the answer to your question is yes, you can, and you can do it with Blender. However on this site we ensure questions and answers are self-contained and as small as possible in scope. I would encourage you to break down all your problems, search for possible duplicates on this site, and post one question per problem. As it stands your question can be solved using many different techniques so it's out of scope for blender stack exchange. Cheers

Comment: you could simply use a csv format. You could read the data easily e.g. with animation nodes (which supports csv pretty well) and it can also position + color objects very easy. Of course, if you don't know animation nodes (free add-on) it might take a little time to learn - but i think it is more than worth it

Comment: if you are asking whether Blender is the right software for this, you might be on the wrong site - this is just for Blender and here are nearly only Blender enthusiasts... ;)